# VB .Net Windows Service Console Messages

Tags: vb.net, windows-services, console

I have a .Net Console application which displays thousands of lines on the console each minute.  I want to convert it to a Windows Service, however I still need a way of viewing these messages.  There are far too many messages to write them to the event log or even a standard log file.  I was wondering if there were a way to write a systray app that could simply intercept these messages from the service and display them in a console window.  I have no need to save older messages, I only need to see current activity.

Answer (score 0):

The service will need to write to shared memory of *some* sort in order to communicate with another program that displays the output.  I think your best bet is to output to a SQL table or something and clear out older entries so there is never more than, say, 1000 records in the table at a time.  Then ping the table a couple times a second in the viewer app and display a streaming view of the output.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the `System.Diagnostics.Trace` type would be perfect for this.  Implement your changes in two phases:

For phase 1, you add a ConsoleTraceListener to your app, and convert all of your current calls to Console to write to Trace instead. This will only maintain your existing behavior, but it sets you up to easily make the change to your new output.

For phase 2, you implement a new TraceListener you can attach instead of the ConsoleTraceListener that does whatever you want with the messages. This might include listening for a connection from your proposed systray or console app.  Even better, I bet a bit of googling will show you a TraceListener that already does what you want.

As for the actual mechanism for communicating the message, my recommendation is to use the standard [SysLog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog) approach. This has the advantages of working existing software for the client, makes it more likely you'll find an [existing TraceListener](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=interop&file=SyslogTraceListener.cs), and many of the existing syslog clients will bring along some automated data mining as a bonus.